# hungarian BBAN validation

Tags: iban, bban

can anybody tell me how to validate Hungarian BBAN account numbres ?
on the internet i have only found that it is 24 numbers length
And in format

```
bbbs sssk cccc cccc cccc cccx
b = National bank code
s = Branch code
c = Account number
x = National check digit
```

but how to calculate x = National check digit ?
I have tried to remove last char and modulo rest by 97 but it does not work
(the result is not 1 for valid account numbers)

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you may need to contact _Hungarian Banking Association_ as the algorithm to calculate the check digit you are looking for is country specific, and they are the most competent organisation to give you guidance in this topic. you can find their contact details __[here](http://www.ecbs.org/iban/hungary-bank-account-number.html)__.

Answer (score 1):

I just finished Hungarian account validation function. This is the first version of this function but it's work well.

```cs
public string sprawdzWegierskitempAccountNumber(string _accountNumberToCheck, bool _iban) //if iban is true then function result will be always IBAN (even if _accountNumberToCheck will be BBAN)
{
    string _accountNumberCorrected = _accountNumberToCheck.Replace(" ", "");
    _accountNumberCorrected = _accountNumberCorrected.Replace("-", "");
    _accountNumberCorrected = _accountNumberCorrected.Replace("//", "");
    _accountNumberCorrected = _accountNumberCorrected.Replace("\\", "");
    string _accountNumberCorrectedFirst = _accountNumberCorrected;
    if (_accountNumberCorrected.Length == 16 || _accountNumberCorrected.Length == 24 || _accountNumberCorrected.Length == 28)
    {

        if (_accountNumberCorrected.Length == 28) //IBAN Account number
        {
            _accountNumberCorrected = _accountNumberCorrected.Substring(4, _accountNumberCorrected.Length - 4); //we don't need first four digits (HUxx)
        }

        string digitToMultiply = "9731";
        int checkResult = 0;
        
        //checking first part of account number
        for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            checkResult = checkResult + int.Parse(_accountNumberCorrected.ToCharArray()[i].ToString()) * int.Parse(digitToMultiply.ToCharArray()[i % 4].ToString());
        }
        checkResult = checkResult % 10;
        checkResult = 10 - checkResult;
        if (checkResult == 10)
        {
            checkResult = 0;
        }
        if (checkResult.ToString() != _accountNumberCorrected.ToCharArray()[7].ToString())
        {
            throw new Exception("Wrong account number");
        }
        else
        {
            //if first part it's ok then checking second part of account number
            checkResult = 0;
            for (int i = 8; i <= _accountNumberCorrected.Length-2; i++)
            {
                checkResult = checkResult + int.Parse(_accountNumberCorrected.ToCharArray()[i].ToString()) * int.Parse(digitToMultiply.ToCharArray()[i % 4].ToString());
            }

            checkResult = checkResult % 10;
            checkResult = 10 - checkResult;
            if (checkResult == 10)
            {
                checkResult = 0;
            }
            if (checkResult.ToString() != _accountNumberCorrected.ToCharArray()[_accountNumberCorrected.Length-1].ToString())
            {
                throw new Exception("Wrong account number");
            }

        }
        
        string tempAccountNumber = _accountNumberCorrected + "173000";

        var db = 0; var iban = 0;
        var maradek = 0;
        string resz = "", ibanstr = "", result = "";

        while (true)
        {

            if (db == 0)
            {
                resz = tempAccountNumber.Substring(0, 9);
                tempAccountNumber = tempAccountNumber.Substring(9, (tempAccountNumber.Length - 9));

            }

            else
            {

                resz = maradek.ToString();
                resz = resz + tempAccountNumber.Substring(0, (9 - db));
                tempAccountNumber = tempAccountNumber.Substring((9 - db), (tempAccountNumber.Length - 9 + db));

            }

            maradek = int.Parse(resz) % 97;

            if (maradek == 0)
                db = 0;
            else
                if (maradek < 10)
                    db = 1;
                else
                    db = 2;

            if ((tempAccountNumber.Length + db) <= 9)
                break;
        }

        if (maradek != 0)
        {
            resz = maradek.ToString();
            resz = resz + tempAccountNumber;
        }
        else
            resz = tempAccountNumber;

        maradek = int.Parse(resz) % 97; ;
        iban = 98 - maradek;
        if (iban < 10)
            ibanstr = "0" + iban.ToString();
        else ibanstr = iban.ToString();
        
        if (_accountNumberCorrected.Length == 16)
        {
            _accountNumberCorrected = _accountNumberCorrected + "00000000";
            _accountNumberCorrectedFirst = _accountNumberCorrectedFirst + "00000000";
        }

        if (_iban)
        {
            result = "HU" + ibanstr + _accountNumberCorrected;
        }
        else
        {
            result = _accountNumberCorrectedFirst;
        }

        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Wrong length of account number");
    }
}
```